# Checking if a String contains the letters I want plus a whitespace at the end of it

Tags: java

Im looking for a way to check if the String the User enters, contains two things:
First: It should start with "hello "(its hello and a whitspace!) or if it starts with a number. If both is false I want to print out false , if one of both is true i print out true.

```
if (text.startsWith("hello ") == false)
{
    if (Character.isDigit(text.CharAt(0)) == false)
    { 
        System.out.println("false"); 
    }

    Syso("true"); 
}
Syso("true");
```

I know that the two If's are not the smartest choice in this case but im fine with this. The only problem I have at the Moment is that if the text is "hello" so without a whitespace it still gives me true. Does it have to do something with the method startsWith? is there another method to use ?

Sorry , My english is bad and I'm knew to programming. But thanks for the feedbak

Comment: I suggest you to use regex

Comment: `"hello".startsWith("hello ") == false`, I can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: It always prints "true" because you made it the last thing this code does regardless of the checks you make.

Comment: It's charAt (n), not CharAt (n). And the keyword 'else' is missing.

Answer (score 1):

You want something to be true if one of two conditions is true. This is thus a logical `or`:

```
System.out.println(text.startsWith("hello ") || Character.isDigit(text.charAt(0)));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (! text.startsWith ("hello ") && ! Character.isDigit (text.charAt (0)) {
          Syso ("false"); 
}
else Syso ("true");
```

This can be further condensend. If (! a && ! b) is equivalent to if (! (a || b)).

```
if (! (text.startsWith ("hello ") || Character.isDigit (text.charAt (0)))) {
          Syso ("false"); 
}
else Syso ("true");
```

Negating the condition is, however, confusing. So if there is no good reason, you should formulate a positive, hence more simple condition:

```
    if (text.startsWith ("hello ") || Character.isDigit (text.charAt (0))) 
              Syso ("true"); 
    else Syso ("false");
```

I can't reproduce your error with the **blank** - maybe you tricked yourself with the too-much-negation?

Note, that you should test your example code to reproduce your error - and cut and paste it, to prevent new errors. String.charAt (0) must start with a lower c in the method name.

Note, that you need an '**else**' after the closing braces, to reach your goal.

Comment: Thanks, for your reply. Thats exactly what I was searching for :)

Comment: @Panikx17: What exactly - I overworked the code, because I've overseen your problem during first, fast reading. Too much negation? Missing else?

Answer (score 0):

The way you included print statements in your code is wrong. The problem in your code is if it doesn't start with 'hello ' it enters the if block. If it doesn't start with a digit, it further enters the inner if, prints false. Once it comes out it prints true and then after outer if it prints a true again.

```
if (str.startsWith("hello ") || Character.isDigit(str.charAt(0))) {
    System.out.println("True");
}
else{
    System.out.println("False");
}
```

Comment: Oh no I meant the way he/she compared is correct. Because he/she wasn't sure if "hello " should be compared that way. They are worried about the white space after "hello"

Comment: I think the line is misleading :) Took that off :) @JBNizet

Answer (score 0):

try using trim() method, trim takes off the white spaces from a text:

```
String txt = "hello ";
System.out.println(txt.trim() + jhon);

console: hellojhon
```